# Set an object property to the negative value of a property in the same object (Javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Lets say I have a Javascript object:

```
var myObj = {
 property1 : 20,
 property2 : -20
}
```

But instead of `-20` for `property2`, I need to take the value of `property1` and convert it to its negative within `property2`:

```
var myObj = {
 property1 : 20,
 property2 : this.property1 * -1
}
```

This doesn't work, but I think it illustrates what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this. Multiplying by -1 is such an easy thing to do, and when you're doing it inline you probably don't even have to type-check to make sure the property you want to multiply is the same data type. Well, I take that back. Unless it's a trivial bit of scripting you should do it anyway, because how can you be sure the value of `property1` hasn't been changed to be NaN?

Comment: I think the more general question is whether, within an object literal, the value of a property can be an expression involving one or more other properties of the same inchoate object.

Comment: (The answer is "no" by the way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest you the following

```
var myObj = {
    property1 : 20,
    get_property2 : function() {
        return this.property1 * -1;
    },
    set_property2 : function(value) {
        this.property1 = value * -1;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Seems that this is a dependant property so it is readonly. But I've edited the code so that it is also writable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. You can assign it later, though:

```
var myObj = {
    property1: 20
};

myObj.property2 = -myObj.property1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var myObj = {
   property1 : 20,
   get property2() {    return this.property1 * -1;   }
};
```

But you can only read `property2` property.

Defining setter of `property2` will not be a problem.
See [JavaScript Getters and Setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) link.